# Sanitizing the LDAP Queries in Java

Tags: java, regex, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

can someone guide me on below code,

```
public String escapeDN (String name) {
       //From RFC 2253 and the / character for JNDI
       final char[] META_CHARS = {'+', '"', '<', '>', ';', '/'};
       String escapedStr = new String(name);
       //Backslash is both a Java and an LDAP escape character, so escape it first
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\","\\\\\\\\"); 
       //Positional characters - see RFC 2253
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\^#","\\\\\\\\#");
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\^ | $","\\\\\\\\ ");
       for (int i=0;i < META_CHARS.length;i++) {
           escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\"+META_CHARS[i],"\\\\\\\\" + META_CHARS[i]);
       }
       return escapedStr;
   }


 public String escapeSearchFilter (String filter) {
       //From RFC 2254
       String escapedStr = new String(filter);
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\","\\\\\\\\5c");
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\\*","\\\\\\\\2a");
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\(","\\\\\\\\28");
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\)","\\\\\\\\29");
       escapedStr = escapedStr.replaceAll("\\\\"+Character.toString('\\u0000'), "\\\\\\\\00");
       return escapedStr;
   }
```

In the above code I can understand the LDAP baseDN and searchFilter values are sanitized before going to execute but I can not understand why and how the methods will work...

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a DN in a generic fashion is a daunting task. I would recommend you use a specific LDAP API like [UnboundID](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html) or [Apache LDAP](https://directory.apache.org/api/java-api.html).

If you would like to see some of the complexities check out: https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/src-html/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/DN.html#line.280

-jim

Comment: Hi jim, I would like to understand why  '\\\\\\\\' replaced with the same no of back slashes again.. what is the benefit of that? is it any thing intentional?

Comment: I know it's too late to answer your question about why you seemingly replace backslashes with the same number of backslashes, but anyway, if someone else is wondering: The actual signature of the method is: replaceAll(String regex, String replacement). So, the first argument is a regex, whereas the second argument is just a String. Remember, in the regexp format you use the backslash for escapement, so \\ means a single backslash but you also need to escape each of these in Java and it becomes \\\\, so double backslash is \\\\\\\\ and you replace it with "\\\\\\\\" which is four backslashes.